# Blank ActiveAdmin pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My ActiveAdmin index page for `ad_images` works fine but new, edit, and view look blank like this...

[image: blank active admin new page]

**`admin/ad_image.rb`** looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdImage do
  permit_params :name, :url, :imageable_type, :imageable_id

  form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
    f.inputs "Ad Image" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :url, as: :file
      f.input :imageable_type
      f.input :imageable_id
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

The AdImage model works normally otherwise. Any clue what's going on?

**UPDATE**

Turns out that "ad_image" conflicts with a formtastic style of the same name... I think? When I remove the "ad_image" class from the form (which is added automatically) everything works fine.

I can give an alias to my ActiveAdmin class like so

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdImage, as: "ImagesForAds"
```

... and the form will appear. But now I can't save anything...

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem you should answer your own question and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit **admin/ad_image.rb** :---

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdImage do
  permit_params :name, :url, :imageable_type, :imageable_id

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Ad Image" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :url, as: :file
      f.input :imageable_type
      f.input :imageable_id
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I've kind of figured it out. Check out my update.